# Discord.js - remove all roles that start with * (asterisk)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need to make a command that first removes the member from all roles that start with an asterisk and then assign a role that would be passed in the argument of the command.

```js
exports.run = (client, message, [where]) => {
    var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === where);

    if (role && where.substring(0, 1) == '*') {
        //remove all roles that start with * from the member, probably some kind of for loop?

        message.member.roles.add(role);
        message.channel.send(message.member.nickname + ' entered the channel ' + where + '.');
    }
    else message.channel.send('Channel' + where + ' does not exist or does not start with *.');
};
```

Can you help me with that for loop? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? if so what are they?

Comment: No, this code works great, but I don't know how to do that for loop to find all the roles that start with * and then remove them from the member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is:

```js
const roles = message.member.roles.cache.array();

for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
      if (roles[i].name.substring(0, 1) == "*") {
            message.member.roles.remove(roles[i]);
      }

}
```